# Vscode not interactive with python. Mac M1 chip

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am on a Mac with M1 chip and I have a problem with my VScode and python. It stays stuck on the ZSH shell even when I type the command to switch to bash (chsh -s /bin/bash). Lets say I run a simple code:

```
import cowsay
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    cowsay.cow("Hello, " + sys.argv[1])
```

I am supposed to be able to type my name in the shell after my python file name and it should print the cow saying Hello, Noah.

When I do so ((base) noahhaitas@Noahs-Mac-mini ~ % python3 itunes.py Noah Haitas), this is what I get as a message in my shell:

```
(base) noahhaitas@Noahs-Mac-mini ~ % python3 itunes.py Noah Haitas
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3: can't open file '/Users/noahhaitas/itunes.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am trying to figure out how I can switch fully to bash and have the $ in front instead of seeing the % of ZSH.

What can be done as this is frustrating and I looked everywhere online and tried pretty much every solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vscode is just an editor, and the system terminal is still applied.

Use the following command in the terminal to switch bash and restart the terminal:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

At the same time, you can also set manually in the vscode terminal. Take Windows as an example:

[image]

Read the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles#_configuring-profiles) for more details about terminal settings.

By the way, there is an error when you run the file. It seems that the python file is not run in the correct directory.

[image]

Comment: Of course, It is done. I didnt know of this feature! Thanks for the help